# DSE: How to encrypt passwords in system.log file

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

We enabled password authentication in cassandra. However all the login passwords we use to login into dse spark shell are logged in system.log file with our user name passwords in plain text.

Is there a way to encrypt these passwords or not log the passwords to log file?

"-Dcassandra.username=[USER_NAME]" "-DcassandraUserNameProp=[USER_NAME]" "-Dcassandra.password=XXXXXXXXX"

It is storing the passowrds in plain text in the above line.

Comment: How are you logging into spark shell?

Comment: dse -u <username> spark

Answer (score 1):

1. Please try to put your credentials into *resources/spark/conf/spark-defaults.properties*

   spark.cassandra.auth.username=
   spark.cassandra.auth.password=
   spark.hadoop.cassandra.username=
   spark.hadoop.cassandra.password=

For multiple users, you may try to copy *resources/spark/conf* (or if you use packages installation, the relevant directory from */etc/dse*) to the particular user home directory and set *SPARK_CONF_DIR* so that is points to that location.

2. You may run Spark Shell in the following way:

   DSE_USERNAME=username DSE_PASSWORD=password dse spark

That is, provide credentials as environment variables instead of command line parameters. This will prevent credentials from being a part of the command.

Comment: We have more then 10 users accessing this cluster and we use LDAP authentication for this. We cannot store the passwords in file as well. However according to datastax documentation I don't see a property for setting credentials in file https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkCassProps.html.

Comment: I added more details about what can you do with your problem. Please let me know you managed to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However we cannot store the passwords in file. is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is it about system.log on the worker machines or the machine where you run Spark Shell? Maybe you should go the official way and file a support ticket?